# Feeding images along with labels to lstm

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to build an lstm model in keras to feed image sequences and also label corresponding to each image. LSTM model should predict the label of image at time t.

Each sequence has 5 images of size 224 x 224 with 3 channels

I am extracting the features from CNN model and feeding the lstm, the features and the labels at each time point.

***Questions-***

**How do I add the labels, for instance, for the first sequence the labels are [0,1,1,2,3]. Each element in the list correspond to each image in the sequence.**

**What is the best way to feed in the labels of each sequence?**

```
seqs=5
channels=3
rows=224
columns=224


inp = Input(shape=(seqs,
                     rows,
                     columns, channels))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(rows,columns,channels),weights="imagenet",include_top=False)

cnn_out = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cnn_base.output)

cnn = Model(inputs=cnn_base.input, outputs=cnn_out)

encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn)(inp)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(output_dim=1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(output_dim=2, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
model = Model([inp], outputs)

optimizer = Nadam(lr=0.002,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-08,schedule_decay=0.004)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the application. But I think the outputs layer should be reflective of the number of classes you have. Maybe using [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) of scikit learn may help you represent your labels, like how its done in Multi class classification. But I am not really sure that is what makes sense in this case!

Comment: I am trying a similar thing, does this work?